# PS4 controller paired with PC won't connect to console

Tags: controllers, ps4

So I paired my PS4 controller to my PC using DS4 windows with Bluetooth and it works splendidly; however, now that I'm trying to do reconnect it to my PS4, it won't. I've tried resetting it with the reset button bellow the L2 button, the share and PS button, nothing works. When I turn the controller on it automatically syncs up with my PC instead of my PS4. Am I gonna have to uninstall DS4 or something?

Comment: have you tried connecting the controller to the PS4 via the USB cable then unplugging it while both are still on?

Answer (score 3):

With the DS4 and PS4 off, connect the DS4 to the PS4 with the USB cable and press the PS button to turn the PS4 ON and pair the DS4 back to the PS4.

You will need to do this every time you want to pair the DS4 back to the PS4.